# Calling a $resource action from inside a user defined $scope function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

**The frontend:** `AngularJS 1.1.5`, which has `ngResource` returning a promise's `$then` function
**The backend:** `Rails 3.2`

**The problem:** Whenever I call the `Card.update` action from inside a function in an AngJS controller, I get no response from attempting to log both the `success` and `error` responses. The `Card` $resource behaves as expected works when calling the `Card.update` action from outside the function.

**Rails Associations**

```
Deck has_and_belongs_to_many :cards
Card has_and_belongs_to_many :decks
```

**Rails routes**

```
resources :cards do
  get '/decks' => 'cards#decks', on: :member
end
```

**Rails Card Controller 'update' action**

```
def update
  @card = Card.where( id: params[:id] ).first

  unless params[:deck_id].nil?
    @deck = Deck.where( id: params[:deck_id] ).first

    @deck.cards << @card
  end

  render json: Card.update( params[:id], params[:card] )
end
```

**Cards Resource Factory**

```
app.factory "Card", ($resource) ->
  $resource "/cards/:id",
    id: "@id"
  ,
    index:
      method: "GET"
      isArray: true

    show:
      method: "GET"
      isArray: false

    create:
      method: "POST"

    update:
      method: "PUT"

    destroy:
      method: "DELETE"

    decks:
      method: "GET"
      isArray: true
      url: 'cards/:id/decks'
```

**Cards update function (inside AngJS Controller):** (Success/error messages aren't logged to the console).

```
$scope.updateCard = ( card_id, old_deck, new_deck ) ->
  console.log 'CardCtrl updateCard function'
  card_id = parseInt(card_id)
  old_deck = parseInt(old_deck)
  new_deck = parseInt(new_deck)

  Card.update( id: card_id, deck_id: new_deck ).$then (success, error) ->
    console.log 'Success'
    console.log success

    console.log 'Error'
    console.log error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Introduction

I solved my own problem. I used this [Github comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2431#issuecomment-18688795) from Misko Hevery as reference.

#### Why my PUT request wasn't executing:

Apparently, in `Angular 1.1.x`, if you ever leave the *angular execution context*, you'll be outside of Angular's `$scope.$apply` function. In my case, I was working with JQuery UI's `sortable` function - whenever a `Card` was placed in a new `Deck`, I wanted to update the `Deck's` cards to reflect that update.

To the best of my understanding, because of this, I was outside the *angular execution context*. `ngResource` wouldn't execute the `PUT` statement and the `$then` function of the Angular's `promise` object will never be called.

#### The solution:

Simply wrapping the `$scope.$apply` function around the `Card.update`action allowed the action to execute, which subsequently allowed the `$then` function to execute. See the code example below for further clarification:

```
$scope.$apply ->
  Card.update(
    id: 1
    deck_id: 2
    front: "HELLO WORLD!"
  ).$then ((success) ->
    console.log "Success"
    console.log success
  ), (error) ->
    console.log "Error"
    console.log error
```

Comment: Also, notice that the $then function takes a success and error callback function, rather than one function with a success and error parameter.